# jQuery Validation with Joomla CMS

Tags: jquery, validation, joomla, jquery-validate, joomla2.5

I use below jquery.validation to validation email at the front-end. It works fine.

```
jQuery(function(){ 
  //checking email is blank or not
  jQuery("#email").validate({
    expression: "if(VAL) return true; else return false;",
    message: "<?php echo JText::_('Error in email'); ?>"
  });
});
```

PHP - Joomla Save Button

```
JToolBarHelper::save();
```

I use joomla native save button to fire to save task in my controller.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
```

My problem is jquery validation does not stop joomla submit. What I want to do is when user click SAVE I want to submit the form only if there are no validation error. How can I do it ? Thanks

Comment: Did you try this- http://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation

Comment: What I want to do is to use above validation. Not the in-built validation

Comment: I have just suggested a workaround.It will not require any jquery.

Comment: I'm supposed to use above validation. Thanks for the link anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May this will be helpful to you-

```
//Joomla 1.5
    function submitbutton(pressbutton) {   
     var isValid = jQuery("#form-id").valid();
     if(isValid){
      submitform(pressbutton); 
     }else{
      return false;
     }
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("#form-id").validate();
    });

//joomla 2.5
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#form-id").validate();
});
Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
{
    var isValid = jQuery("#form-id").valid();
    if(isValid){
        Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('form-id'));  
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

for more details - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid